# Convert list and add to db in separate rows

Tags: python, postgresql

I have values such as `[(1,), (2,), (3,)]`. I want to extract these values as list `[1,2,3]`. Also I am trying to insert these values in db such that the id to which they point is same, but are added in different rows.

For example

```
 id | value
  1 | 1
  1 | 2
  1 | 3
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```py
import pandas_datareader as dr
import sqlite3
    
con = sqlite3.connect("*databasename*.sqlite")
c = con.cursor()
con.commit()
    
try:
   df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * from *tablename*, con, index_col = "id"')
except:
   c.execute('CREATE TABLE *tablename*(id text, value text)')
   df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * from *tablename*, con, index_col = "id"')
    
   for i in range(len(df)):
       sql = "INSERT INTO *tablename* (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)"
       val = (df.iloc[i, 0], df.iloc[i, 1])
       c.execute(sql, val)
       con.commit()
```

- The first part is your imports of course.
- The next section establishes your SQLite connection.
- The third section tries to read a table from a database. If it does not exist it will throw an exception which will then create the table that does not exist and then read the table in pandas dataframe form.
- Finally, the last section will insert each item into the database. It will need to be changed a little for whatever data you decide to put in there. Otherwise, it will keep putting the same information in it over and over again. Hopefully this helps.